# Update Drupal core from a low version

Tags: updating

I have to update a website from 7.14 to 7.31.

I feel like this contains a lot of risks. As anyone updated so many versions? What are your recommendations ?

I figured it would be better to update version per version instead of applying the 7.31 update right away.
I made sure the core was not modified.

Thanks,

Comment: The core upgrade will be fine, everything else is down to what modules you have installed, and what versions _they're_ at. Try it, test it, then you'll know; that's the only real way to do it, anything anyone came up with here would be a guess

Comment: Google "Drupal itok change".  This occurred at either 7.19 or 7.20.  This impacted some people in adverse ways.  While it wasn't a dangerous change, some people were not happy with it, and it did break some code that didn't leverage the API properly.

Comment: I do remember about the itok change we had to do on some other site. Didn't affect us much, but seeing as this is a website we just moved back to us, it might be a pain @MPD

Comment: @Clive : Yeah I guess that's the best way.

Answer (score 2):

As long as core is not modified in any way, there should be no risks of updating it straight from 7.14 to 7.31. It will apply all database updates from each version in between. There's literally no difference in doing it one version at a time compared to doing it straight to 7.31.

But as always, test it in a development environment before doing it in production and always make backups.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it before without any problem using drush in my test environment for an old project. My core did not have any modification or hack. Check also that your modules are up to date.

**Please make sure before doing anything to do the proper backups to the database and code.**